Can't connect archlinux pc with wifi?
I am using Archlinux OS, but it seems that for some wifi, it cant be connected?
Do you know if the problem is the wifi, or I can resolve it?
Here it is how it looks:


Answered by my professor which I don't know if he has an acc.
He said to click "Wifi security" and in the end of the window complete username and password without @ if username is an email.
And it worked
